# gdm3 login loop 19.04

Tags: login, .desktop, gnome-shell-extension

I was working on the computer and installed gnome tweak tool I went to the extensions and tried to turn on system monitor ext. However, for some reason, it locked the computer up and now when I log in it keeps looping back to gdm3 login screen.

Comment: This was dealing with gnome extensions. When I was turning on an extension the tweak tool locked the desktop up. I had to force a hard shutdown by turning off the computer and when I rebooted the system is when the login started.

Comment: The extension that locked up the computer was the system-monitor extension.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why, but apparently the lockup corrupted something in the gnome-shell directory. To fix I renamed the file `.local/share/gnome-shell` to `./local/share/gnome-shell.old`. I then rebooted the computer.